# How do I set AppBar action button color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to set the color of my `AppBar` action icons by using themes but it's just not working for some reason. Here's my minimal code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.purple),
        primaryIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.red),
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.amber)
      ),
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.green),
        actionsIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.yellow),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add))
        ]
      )
    ));
  }
}
```

- None of the `iconTheme` color values have any effect.
- Settings the opacity in either the `MaterialApp.iconTheme`, `AppBar.iconTheme` or `AppBar.actionsIconTheme` does actually take effect
- Explicitly setting `Icon.color` does work but I don't think I should have to do that right?

How do I get the `IconButton` to respect my theme?

Thanks
Thomas

EDIT: By using a `Icon` directly instead of an `IconButton` I'm actually able to get the icon to respect my theme, but how do I make that clickable? According to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/actions.html an `IconButton` is the most common widget to use in `AppBar.actions`. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, apparently my problem was that I hadn't defined the `onPressed` property of the `IconButton`. Once I added that, my theme was applied properly.

I knew it was a required property but I didn't get any error when building/running the app.

Comment: Be careful : by setting `onPressed` property to `null` on any kind of button, it will be disabled and will be styled as disabled (you can have a try with a basic `RaisedButton`). I personnaly write first: `onPressed: (){}` for every button I use in UI.

Comment: Man, I hate `null`s

Comment: Well too bad, sometimes it is the default value for callback functions

Comment: Yeah :/

Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 1):

Make class of common for App Bar Widget

```
enum ButtontType {
  back,
  menu
}

class topBarWidget {

//region TopBar
  static AppBar createTopBar(
  {
    String title,
    double elevation = 1.5,
    TextStyle titleStyle,
    Widget titleWidget,
    List<ButtontType> leftIcons = const [],
    List<ButtontType> rightIcons = const [],
    ButtonTapCallback action,
    EdgeInsetsDirectional padding = const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 10, end: 10.0),
    Color backgroundColor,
    Color iconColor,
    bool centerTitle = true}) {
var titleText = titleWidget;

if (titleText == null) {
  titleText = Text(
    title,
    softWrap: true,
    style: txtStyle,
    ),
  );
}

var leftmenuWidget;
List<Widget> rightRowChildern = [];

final size = 18.0;
final tapAreasize = 32.0;

if (leftIcons.length > 0) {
  List<Widget> mainRowChildern = [];
  mainRowChildern.add(Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0)));
  for (int i = 0; i < leftIcons.length; i++) {

    final menuIconImage = Image.asset(_getImageName(type: leftIcons[i]),color: Colors.black,);
    final menuIconImageSizeBox = SizedBox(child: menuIconImage, width: size, height: size,);
    // ignore: unnecessary_statements
    final menuIconAction = Container(color: Colors.transparent,child: InkWell(onTap: () {(action != null) ? action(leftIcons[i]) : null;},child: ClipOval(child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center,width: tapAreasize,height: tapAreasize,color: Colors.transparent,child:menuIconImageSizeBox,),),),);
    //final menuIconAction = InkWell(child: menuIconImageSizeBox, onTap: () => (action != null) ? action(leftIcons[i]) : null, );
    mainRowChildern.add(menuIconAction);
  }

  leftmenuWidget = Row(children: mainRowChildern, mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,);
}

if (rightIcons.length > 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < rightIcons.length; i++) {

    Widget menuIconImage = Image.asset(_getImageName(type: rightIcons[i]),color: Colors.black,);

    if(_getImageName(type: rightIcons[i]) == _getImageName(type: ButtontType.notificationUnread)){
      menuIconImage = Image.asset(_getImageName(type: rightIcons[i]),);
    } else{
      menuIconImage = Image.asset(_getImageName(type: rightIcons[i]),color: Colors.yellow,);
    }

    var menuIconImageSizeBox;
    menuIconImageSizeBox = SizedBox(child: menuIconImage, width: size * 1.5, height: size * 1.5,);
    final menuIconAction = InkWell(child: menuIconImageSizeBox, onTap: () => (action != null) ? action(rightIcons[i]) : null,);
    rightRowChildern.add(menuIconAction);

    if (i != (rightIcons.length - 1)) {
      rightRowChildern.add(Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0)));
    }
  }
  rightRowChildern.add(Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0)));
  rightRowChildern = [
    Row(
      children: rightRowChildern,
    )
  ];
}

var topBar = AppBar(
  elevation: elevation,
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
  leading: leftmenuWidget ?? SizedBox(),
  actions: rightRowChildern,
  title: titleText,
  centerTitle: centerTitle,
  titleSpacing: 0,
);

return topBar;
  }
  //endregion


static String _getImageName({ButtontType type}) {
    var iconName;
   if (type == ButtontType.back) {
      iconName = 'images/back.png';
    } else if (type == ButtontType.menu) {
      iconName = 'images/menu.png';
    } 
    return iconName;
  }
}
```

Now sample of **How to use**

```
// Appbar for notes page
final appBar = topBarWidget.createTopBar(
    titleStyle: txtStyle,
    title: "App Bar",
    leftIcons: [ButtontType.back],
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    action: (ButtontType type) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });

   var scaffold = Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: scaffoldBuilder,
    );
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean by respecting your theme that you want them to be white when your app bar is dark and vice versa, you just have to use `brightness` attribute in the app bar

Eg:

```
AppBar(
  backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(1023, 255, 112, 5),
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  title: Text(
    'title',
  ),
)
```

or if you want to continue your work with what you have right now you can wrap your Icon with an Inkwell and you will get onTap to manage touches!

Comment: Hm, settings `brightness` has no effect either. I'm pretty new at this but currently the `AppBar` title and any `Drawer` icon I add to the bar are white, while the `IconButton` is gray. I would like all of them to be the same color. I just wrote "respect my theme" because I assumed that that's where the title and and drawer icon color (white) was taken from.

Comment: try to make it light instead of dark

Comment: Still no change I'm afraid

Comment: that's really odd, I don't know why this happens, try creating a new project and applying this solution to it, because this is what I used previously in my projects, or you can try the second half of the solution

Comment: Tried on a pristine project with the same result :/

Thanks though!

Comment: sorry to hear that, did the second half help you ?

Comment: It seems to work ok though the widget ends up being much smaller and is placed very close to the screen edge

Comment: try playing with it like placing it inside a column or a container, or even changing its size may help

Comment: I found the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what was the problem? you can provide an answer to people having the same issue or I can edit my answer if you let me know how you did it

Answer (score 0):

Ahem, all these answers are not really best practices.

Take and define a PrimaryIconTheme and that gets entered in two places in your AppBar Theme, i.e. iconTheme and actionsIconTheme